# AWS Cloudwatch changes retention time

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using AWS with terraform. If I let the default settings, running the terraform plan I get an update on the retention days, from 30 to 90. If I run the terraform apply the retention changes but after a random period it returns to 30 days and the plan suggests me to re-apply the change to 90 days.

Why there is this change? What can I have miss?
Thanks everyone

Comment: This is not about terraform, this is about *something* changing the configuration of your resources. Talk to whoever created your account, manages your organization, etc. to figure out what automatic processes they have in place that causes this. Alternatively try tracking the changes down via AWS Config or CloudTrail.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, I found the issue on Cloudtrail tracking.